# How To Get Twitter Followes_Count To echo with commas

Tags: twitter

I am working on pulling the number of twitter followers into my Wordpress page but running into a small problem I cannot figure out. I imagine it would be a quick fix...do you think you can help?

The issue is the output reads:
11131

I would like it to read:
11,131

You see the comma in the correct position...not sure how to get that to render in the right format. Here is the code I am working with:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/user/lookup.json?screen_name=erinschreyer'), true);
echo $data[0]['followers_count'];
?>
```

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work with that:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=erinschreyer'), true);
$followers = $data[0]['followers_count'];
echo number_format($followers);
?>
```

See [number_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: Getting this error:

Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.twitter.com/1/user/lookup.json?screen_name=erinschreyer) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in /home4/eschreye/public_html/erinschreyer.com/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/subscriptions.php on line 639
0 other followers

Comment: because the [site](https://api.twitter.com/1/user/lookup.json?screen_name=erinschreyer) does not exists..you can get user information with this link: https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=USERNAME

Comment: @user1447958 i've updated my answer, should work now..no you forgot an 's' in the url

Comment: **-1**. This code will not work as of tomorrow (11th) - because the version 1.0 API is deprecated and being **retired tomorrow**. @user1447958 Your code will literally stop working tomorrow.